# I need to directly access shared folder in linux with out using the root user previlage.Host Win7, Guest Linux Mint 17.2?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I need to directly access shared folder in Linux Mint (hosted in Oracle VirtualBox 5.0.2r) with out using the root user privilege.
I have tried to change the user and user group using chown command but it did not work.

#### `chown -R go:go sf_MINT-SHARE/`

```
go media # chown -R go:go sf_MINT-SHARE/
go media # ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Sep  2 14:32 ./
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root   4096 Sep  1 15:23 ../
drwxrwx---  1 root vboxsf 4096 Sep  4 10:35 sf_MINT-SHARE/
```

Also, I have tried with `adduser` command as well:

```
sudo adduser go vboxsf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're currently logged in to the `go` account, the effects of running `sudo adduser go vboxsf` won't take effect immediately: group membership is only checked at login time, so your currently-running session won't "know" that you're in the vboxsf group until you log out and log back in.

However, logging out and back in again can be inconvenient sometimes, so you can try the following in your currently-open terminal window: immediately after running `sudo adduser go (group name)`, run:

`exec sudo su -l $USER`

This replaces your current terminal session with a new login session, but doesn't log you out of Cinnamon. So within your terminal session, you will now be considered a member of the `vboxsf` group, with all its privileges, and you'll be able to run any shell commands you like with access to the sf_MINT-SHARE folder.

Do note, though, that this will only refresh your group membership for *that terminal session*. If you, say, launch the Nemo file manager by clicking on its icon in the Cinnamon quick-launch bar next to the menu, that program will still be running under your login session, which doesn't yet "know" about your membership in the vboxsf group. So if you want to use Nemo to manage files in your shared folder, you'll need to log out of Cinnamon and log back in again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have run the exec command.Now I can directly access the folder.But still can not access the files in that sf_MINT-SHARE folder.When I run list command It gives Protocol error.I know that this is due to shared folder mounted in each time when I start the VirtualBox Linux Mint OS.Any permanent solution?

Comment: @jshunt - That might be a different issue. I don't have experience with that one, but https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15868 suggests that the problem MIGHT be that your folder name in /media has the same name as the share. If that doesn't help, try http://serverfault.com/questions/674974/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder or try asking a new question about your new problem. (That way it will get more people seeing it).